# could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.reportviewer.winforms' using visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using visual studio 2019 with .NET framework 4.7.2 for my WinForms project. I have a report form that works fine when I run the project from Visual Studio, but when I run the ".exe" file inside bin/debug/app.publish folder, I am getting below error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

In my project, I have tried

> "Corrected.Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms 150.1358.0"

as well as

> "Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms 150.1537.0"

Both packages installes the following dll inside my project:

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
```

I have tried many suggested solutions from Stack overflow and other resources but none of them solved may problem.

[image: below image shows dll files inside my project references]

Here is the full exception message:

```
    ************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
   at electric_shop_system.forms.reports_dashboard.InitializeComponent()
   at electric_shop_system.forms.reports_dashboard..ctor()
   at electric_shop_system.main.open_reports_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: if you expand the references under the project, what version is listed in the properties.  Is specific version true or copy local true?

Comment: @terrencep, please see the image that I have added to the question.

Comment: that looks good.  I would just try removing this nuget package and try re-adding 150.1537.0, and if you have other class libraries that use this reference, they need to be compatible with 150.1537.0.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms

Comment: @terrencep, I have tried removing and re-installing these packages, nothing has changed.

Comment: Set "specific version" to False :)

Comment: @Elastep, tried your suggestion, nothing has changed. Same error.

Comment: Do you see any warnings when you rebuild your project?

Comment: @Elastep, there isn't any warnings.

Comment: Are you building in Any CPU mode?

Comment: @Elastep, yes I am building in Any CPU mode.

Comment: Find that dll and manually put it inside the build directory. Just to see if it still complains. Check to make sure that PublicKeyToken matches.

Comment: @Elastep, the DLL is inside the directory.

Comment: One more idea: Check the app.config file and make sure there's no binding redirect set.

Comment: And if there's no, try adding one :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, it seems like there reference mismatch that nuget isn't cleaning up.  It could be a package reference in the csproj file or app.config.  You'll have to manually edit it out.

One workaround though is to take the dll you want, copy it into a lib folder **outside** of the build folder that gets cleaned and reference that dll.  You can reference the dll in your new lib folder by right clicking your project and then going to add > project refence.  Then you can browse to the correct one.

Comment: Your answer is not clear. And I think I have tried all these, still getting the same error.

Comment: I have tried every suggestion but the error still there. Even I changed the DLL version.